# Passing data from a Pop up back to its Parent

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

The parent class activity consists of adapters and recycler views. Using one of the adapters the one click is set for images. If an image is clicked it opens a pop-up and the pop have some sliders and text fields. And the pop-up will collect data from users.

Now I need this data, not in the adapter class but I need it in the parent class.

So can I proceed with this execution? So can anyone help to provide me with a suitable way to create the pop-up and transfer data to the adapter class and then to the parent class?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Simply store the data by some mean (pojo, text file, preferences, database, ...). Then read the data from the parent, when you dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Can you please explain some what briefly about POJO or preference method and database cannot be used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining you are navigating between fragments, the easiest way to do this is to use a SharedViewModel. Both the parent and the dialog will be able to access the data contained in it.

This link should help: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing